# Scale down resolution of images with Media

Tags: media

I have always been using the combination of [IMCE](https://drupal.org/project/imce) and CKEditor and I am quite happy with it. Lately I tried installing [Media](https://drupal.org/project/media), WYSIWYG and CKEditor because it looks like this combination is much more feature rich. The only key thing that seems to be missing is a maximum resolution setting for uploading images. This works perfectly with the IMCE combination but I cannot find a setting anywhere in the Media combination. Am I missing something or is there someway I can get uploaded images to be down scaled automatically?